# convex path - how to?

Tags: android, canvas

Could someone explain me how `convex` path is calculated? I need to draw some `cubic` and additionally some lines but then path is shown as non `convex`. However when I leave only `lines` or just `cubic` it is then `convex`. The problem is that I need some non regular shaped background and need `Convex path` for shadow outline but can't get how I could connect drawing `cubic` with some lines to make `convex path` if it is even possible

Comment: post the shape / path you want to get

Comment: The shape would something similar to https://www.dropbox.com/s/ptgu5zwpzk5ydi0/Screen%20Shot%202018-03-14%20at%2009.24.00.png?dl=0

Comment: and its a white part or grey one?

Comment: sorry, white part, that would need to drop shadow

Comment: you need it for `Outline#setConvexPath`?

Comment: yes, from what I have discovered this would be the only way to drop shadow for such custom shape, but I might be wrong

Comment: Just elevation, using `override fun getOutline(outline: Outline)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> A path is convex if it has a single contour, and only ever curves in a single direction.

Convex means it keeps bending / rotating in one direction, and one direction only. You really have to make sure that all your angles and curves add up. If your curve connects to a line it has to have the same angle or be "more convex", I hope the following 2 images will clear this up.

The picture below is *not* convex. That's also likely your problem. The line connects to a curve, but the curve has a different angle than the line and it will change the direction where it connects. See where the line goes down but instead of continuing the downwards-motion it suddenly goes up again. Instead of keeping one direction it will change for a moment where line and curve meet.

[image]

The above Image is exaggerated for clarity, but even small errors in the connection between the line and curve will trigger an error.

The next line connects to a curve with a steeper angle. This is convex and won't be a problem. See how the whole contour keeps a single motion in one direction, depending in which direction you follow it it keeps turning left/right.

[image]

I answered because I was facing a similar issue recently and I feel your pain. I recommend pen and paper to double and triple check the math and to use a small epsilon value to account for rounding errors etc... You really have to nail the math, because if your line and curve connection is just off by very little it will throw that exception.

*Sorry for my bad paint skills*

Comment: Thanks, great explanation, now I see that my current shape https://www.dropbox.com/s/ptgu5zwpzk5ydi0/Screen%20Shot%202018-03-14%20at%2009.24.00.png?dl=0 would not be convex, but would it even be possible to draw it using convex path?

Comment: @user2141889 nope, won't work. But you can always create a custom view/drawable and draw some gray "shadow" (gradients) yourself...that's what I ended up doing in one case